# Attach and detach listeners to Serilog on the fly?

Tags: serilog

Is it possible to add or remove listeners / sinks dynamically using Serilog? I see from the [configuration documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics) that sinks are determined in the source code by calling `WriteTo`. I suppose I can create a section in my application startup to determine whether to register a sink or not. But is there something similar to the way ETW publish and subscribe events? For example we can run Perfview to listen to ETW events on the fly.